# "scrapy: command not found" on running through shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, web-scraping

I have a shell script through which I am running multiple test scripts, crawling data with Scrapy and navigating to multiple directories. The script looks something like this :

```
export PATH=$PATH
echo $PATH
cd wait/test/ScrapyCrawl
python runner.py #Test file
scrapy crawl Flipkart
scrapy crawl shopin1
scrapy crawl Happily
scrapy crawl Healthkart
scrapy crawl Dezains
scrapy crawl Fnp
scrapy crawl Vmate
scrapy crawl Exlives
scrapy crawl Dgifts
scrapy crawl Babyoye
scrapy crawl Purp
scrapy crawl Fabf
scrapy crawl Zansaar
scrapy crawl Shop19
scrapy crawl Engrave
scrapy crawl Carat
scrapy crawl Todu
scrapy crawl Hit
scrapy crawl Limeroad
scrapy crawl Perfico
python runner2.py #Test file
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
cd subscribe/test/ScrapyCrawl
python runner.py #Test file
scrapy crawl Flipkart
scrapy crawl shopin1
scrapy crawl Happily
scrapy crawl Healthkart
scrapy crawl Dezains
scrapy crawl Fnp
scrapy crawl Vmate
scrapy crawl Exlives
scrapy crawl Dgifts
scrapy crawl Babyoye
scrapy crawl Purp
scrapy crawl Fabf
scrapy crawl Zansaar
scrapy crawl Shop19
scrapy crawl Engrave
scrapy crawl Carat
scrapy crawl Todu
scrapy crawl Hit
scrapy crawl Limeroad
scrapy crawl Perfico
python runner2.py #Test file.
```

But when I run the script, the python scripts run properly but it throws error

```
script2.sh: line 7: scrapy: command not found
script2.sh: line 8: scrapy: command not found
script2.sh: line 9: scrapy: command not found
script2.sh: line 10: scrapy: command not found
script2.sh: line 11: scrapy: command not found
```

and so on .. wherever scrapy is called. Please help. I have already used `export PATH=$PATH`. I am new to shell scripting. Thanks.

Comment: perhaps adding `PATH=$PATH:.` or changing `scrapy ....` to `./scrapy ....` may help

Comment: @anishsane I have already used `export PATH=$PATH`. Adding `PATH=$PATH` will make a difference?

Comment: Not `PATH=$PATH`, add `PATH=$PATH:.` ... But, changing `scrapy` to `./scrapy` is better option. e.g. `./scrapy crawl Flipkart`

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue... Instead of using `export PATH=$PATH`m I included the path of scrapy and now used `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`